# Selecting a single UILabel in a UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I created a horizontal UICollectionView which display the 12 months and i need the user to select one of those, in order to do that I used `collectionCell.isUserInteractionEnabled=true` and a `UITapGestureRecognizer` but this returns the months in the whole page.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let collectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "monthCollectionView", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! AttendenceCollectionViewCell
    collectionCell.collectionViewCellLabel.text=monthArray[indexPath.item]
    collectionCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    collectionCell.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(customMonth(month:tap:)))
    collectionCell.collectionViewCellLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    collectionCell.collectionViewCellLabel.isEnabled=true
    collectionCell.isExclusiveTouch=true

    customMonth(month:monthArray[indexPath.item],tap: tapGesture)


    return collectionCell
}


@objc func customMonth(month:String,tap:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    print("\n",month,"\n")
```

Output:

> Aug
>
> Sep
>
> Oct
>
> Nov
>
> Dec
>
> Apr
>
> Mar
>
> Feb
>
> Jan

Comment: Using UITapGestureRecognizer with UICollectionView is like using any gesture recognizer with UITableView.  It's a slippery slope.

Comment: Why don't you use didSelectRowAt? Why do you use tapGesture?

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using the delegate method of collectionView, `didSelectItemAt()` instead of using a gesture recogniser.

Answer (score 0):

While exploring I found out that we can use

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

for selecting an item in a UICollectionView

it is implemented like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedMonth=monthArray[indexPath.item]
    collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    print("\n\n",selectedMonth)
  }
```